# ¿div que se ponga encima del div que lo contiene?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente código que dinámicamente pone unas imágenes arrastrables en encima de otra imagen. Al poner encima el ratón en el `div` sensor aparece el info pero, cuando éste está en una esquina, el `div` info se cubre por el `div` que lo contiene`.

Código:

```css
.info {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 1em);
  top: 45%;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 0.1em 4em;
  border-radius: 2.2em;
  font-family: arial;
  background: #BFBFBF;
  color: white;
  transition: all ease .3s;
  transform: translateX(-57%) translateY(-50%);
}

.sensor:hover .info {
  opacity: 2;
  transform: translateX(-58%) translateY(-158%);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.img-sensor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sensor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#plano {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px/9;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px ridge;
  border-color: gainsboro;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p>Algo de texto aquí para ver el problema</p>

<div id="contenido-plano">
  <div id="plano">
    <img class="img-sensor" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/eee">
    <div style="top:10px; left:100px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1">
      <div class="info">
        Sensor1
        <br>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:359px; left:252px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="3">
      <div class="info">
        Sensor2
        <br>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:252px; left:571px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="4">
      <div class="info">
        Sensor3
        <br>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Alcides Salazar, por favor no coloques el código que genera la página, comparte el código ya generado para que podamos ver el problema. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y completa el [tour] para más información (y para ganar una medalla más).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Creo que lo que importa es el css y el nombre de los divs, creo.

Comment: 100% de acuerdo con eso. Por eso es por lo que es importante que compartas una versión en la que se pueda ver el problema. El editor provee una herramienta para añadir código ejecutable (HTML, CSS y JS, el icono es algo así `<>`) y que sería de gran ayuda para poder reproducir el problema y asistirte a solucionarlo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Listo edite, gracias por la recomendacion

Comment: Ahora que ya se puede ver el código en funcionamiento, ¿cuál de los 3 puntos verdes genera el problema? ¿Cuáles serían los pasos para reproducirlo?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Cuando este esta en el top: 0 y left: 0 y pongo el raton encima debe aparecer el div info encima del sensor, pero este se tapa con el div que lo contiene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El pop-up deja de verse porque se sale del contenedor que tiene un `overflow:hidden` (y todo lo que exceda el contenedor se esconderá por ello). La solución sería quitarle el `overflow: hidden` a `#plano` para que cuando un elemento se salga del contenedor se siga mostrando la parte que queda fuera:

```css
.info {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 1em);
  top: 45%;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 0.1em 4em;
  border-radius: 2.2em;
  font-family: arial;
  background: #BFBFBF;
  color: white;
  transition: all ease .3s;
  transform: translateX(-57%) translateY(-50%);
}

.sensor:hover .info {
  opacity: 2;
  transform: translateX(-58%) translateY(-158%);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.img-sensor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sensor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#plano {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px/9;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px ridge;
  border-color: gainsboro;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p>Algo de texto aquí para ver el problema</p>

<div id="contenido-plano">
  <div id="plano">
    <img class="img-sensor" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/eee">
    <div style="top:10px; left:100px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1">
      <div class="info">
        Sensor1
        <br>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:359px; left:252px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="3">
      <div class="info">
        Sensor2
        <br>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:252px; left:571px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="4">
      <div class="info">
        Sensor3
        <br>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```